# Customizing object "create" in knockoutjs - property bindings work on load, but not when creating new object

Tags: knockout.js

I am translating my model from the server using ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping) method, so that i can add more properties to my sub models.

following the example here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html  =>  "Customizing object construction using “create”

here is my code:

```
var Employer = function (data) { 
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this); 
        this.Foo = ko.observable("bar"); // added properties will go here. 

        console.log(this.Foo());      // i see this getting called OK on initial creation, and subsequent creations
        console.log(this.Name()); // ** this is only OK during initial creation, but on subsequent times i get "[Object] does not have a property Name" this property comes from the server model..** 
        }; 

        var mapping = {     
            'Employers' : { 
                create: function (options) {
                     var e = new Employer(options.data);
                     return e;
                } 
            } 
        }; 

        model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

so far this works ok!

the problem happens here:

```
        model.addEmployer = function (options, o2) {
            var e = new Employer(options);
             this.Resume.Employers.push(e);
        };
```

i am missing something here..   when i want to add a new object to the collection, it  is missing all the properties that came from the model (from the server) which were added on with this line "ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this); " inside the Employer constructor.

i am guessing i need to repeat some similar mapping inside the addEmployer function that will re-bind all server side properties to the client model

here is how i'm calling addEmployer:

```
 <button data-bind="click: addEmployer">...</button>
```

**UPDATE**

what it boils down to, is when declaring 'create' event in the mapping, that function receives **options** object, which has **options.data** which can be used in this call: *ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this);* .. i am not sure how to get this type of object in my addEmployer handler, to provide necessary bindings for all the properties that exist on Employer object on the servier.

i can sort of hack it by preserving that options.data from initial binding, and re-using that in the addEmployer handler. the problem with that, is it will have all the properties set from that initial object.

what i basically need, is EmployerMappingOptions object that is empty. in the above implementation, options.data comes pre-populated with data on the first Employer object in my collection. **how can i get that mapping data for empty Employer model**?

Comment: It is correct that you are passing _this_ as destination for the mapping transformation inside the addEmployer method? Perhaps you wanted to load data into the new employer _e_?

Comment: @Grim yep, i've tried a few approaches here.. i'll update my question with it.

Comment: WHy are you mapping twice first, in side the constructor and then again when it returns?

Comment: How you calling the _addEmployer_ method of your model? With data coming from the server? Or directly within the page (e.g. from a binding, either directly or not)?

Comment: @Grim calling it from a binding. i added the code.

Comment: @Anders you're right, i was probably just testing different ways.. i  left only the call inside the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out **a** solution.

1. expose the sub-class (sub-model) in question as a property of the main Model

   public ResumeEmployer EmptyEmployer { 
           get { return new ResumeEmployer(); } }
2. create a JSON representation of it

   var newEmployerJson = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EmptyEmployer));
3. when creating new employer on the client, use the empty definition json for bindings

   ```
       var Employer = function (data) { 
           if (data)
               ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this);   // existing data in serialized model
           else
               ko.mapping.fromJS(newEmployerJson, {}, this); // json of single empty Employer class 
           ... 
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you do not add any data when mapping in the add function

Either: give it a dummy data object
http://jsfiddle.net/mfauL/1/

```
this.Employers.push(new EmployerViewModel({ Name: "" }));
```

Or explicit declare the Name observable (Preffered way)
http://jsfiddle.net/mfauL/2/

```
EmployerViewModel = function (data) { 
    this.Foo = ko.observable("bar"); 
    this.Name = ko.observable(); 

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this); 
};
```

Comment: like i said the model is coming from the server.
the initial data variable has the entire JSON of my model and sub models. the point of doing the above, is to still be able to add things to sub model. .. and the point of that mapping is to add all the properties from that model that came from the server. this actually works on the first binding.. it just gets lost when i add new employer

Comment: i am trying to avoid having to re-define my whole model in javascript code, since it is coming from the server.

Comment: i thought the whole point of this:  ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, this);      in the constructor, is that it will add all the bindings to properties that came from initial JSON

Comment: No its not that automagic, javascript is untyped and it does cant track on viewmodel type. It does however help with keeping viewmodel in sync with server data

Comment: right. i wasn't expecting it to give strong typing to js. it does however work the first time because it uses an object from server (in  json dump) to figure out which properties should be on it. I Just need to repeat this process when adding new objects. surely this is a common use case ?